# Variable showing as undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am having trouble with passing the results of checkboxes from my view to the controller and just get "undefined" in the console log.

FYI - I have my controller as "camp".

In my view I have the following:

```
   <div  style="padding:20px;">
      <h5>Add a Business</h5>
      <md-content style="padding:20px;">

       <md-checkbox 
       ng-repeat="business in camp.businesses" 
       ng-model="business.selected" 
       aria-label="Checkbox"
       >
        {{business.business_name}}
      </md-checkbox>

      </md-content>

      <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="camp.addBusinesses(business)">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add 
      </md-button>

    </div>
```

In my controller I have the following function in an "angular.extend()"

```
addBusinesses: function(val){
  console.log('Display Results: ',  val);
}
```

If I just use the function to log the click event, it's fine. But when I try to pass the "business" object, it says "undefined".

What am I missing here???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your `<md-button>` is outside the `ng-repeat`. Your `ng-repeat` ends with the `</md-checkbox>` so when it gets to the button, `business` is indeed undefined.

Try reformatting your code so that the button is still within the scope of the `ng-repeat`. Maybe you want the repeat on the `md-content` instead? I'm not sure what the page is supposed to look like so I can't advise more than that.

Comment: thanks for the response. For some reason I was expecting that "business" var from the loop to be available outside of the ng-repeat. I created a var in the controller and I got it working.